# Hide div if the URL has those words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, this works with a word,  but i want to add multi words, example, "one", "two", "three" etc..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("one") > -1) {
       $( ".hideif" ).hide();
    }
});
```

some help thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array and see if `some` of the words in the array are `.include`d in the `href`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const words = ['one', 'two', three'];
    if (words.some(word => window.location.href.includes(word))) {
       $( ".hideif" ).hide();
    }
});
```